# A cool icon for accepted answer

Tags: feature-request, design, accepted-answer

I saw the Seasoned Advice site has a silver-cover icon (as in, this one's ready to serve) to mark questions with accepted answers.

Can we do something like that?  Perhaps a Torah scroll icon or something else?  Maybe someone could think of something distinctly Jewish that connotes being finished or closed.

Comment: We definitely can (or could have when the site was designed). This post would be stronger if you suggest an appropriate designation. A Torah Scroll icon doesn't denote completion to me.

Comment: @DoubleAA To me either - that's why I was hoping someone would come up with a spiffy idea.

Comment: If we could fit the hadran over the accepted answer space...

Comment: related http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/384/759

Comment: You should also see the badges on [Android.se] and the vote arrows on [money.se]